# Angular ASP.NET SQL: Send table variable value to another component

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, get, put

I have a table in angular created by GETting the table information from my SQL database. I am working on creating an edit button that update the table values with what I input. Currently I have it so the user can enter the ID in the form where things get updated. However, I want to be able to pass the ID to the form rather than allowing the user to enter it.

This is what I have so far.

**Table HTML**  *The button edit passes the ID value to the Query string and sends it to the editing page along with redirecting the user to the edit page. After this point I'm not sure how to get the value from the query string to the edit component ts file.*

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
      <td>
        <button [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" routerLink="/editweatherforecast/{{forecast.ID}}"> //This is to redirect to editing
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M12.146.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-10 10a.5.5 0 0 1-.168.11l-5 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.65-.65l2-5a.5.5 0 0 1 .11-.168l10-10zM11.207 2.5 13.5 4.793 14.793 3.5 12.5 1.207 11.207 2.5zm1.586 3L10.5 3.207 4 9.707V10h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.293l6.5-6.5zm-9.761 5.175-.106.106-1.528 3.821 3.821-1.528.106-.106A.5.5 0 0 1 5 12.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.468-.325z" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" (click)="deleteData(forecast)" style="margin:5px;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z" />
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>{{forecast.ID}}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.Date }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.TemperatureC }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.TemperatureF }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.Summary }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

**Edit Form TS File** *Here I create a weatherform and declare the 5 variables I have. Currently I have each variable set to take in input data but I need the ID to simply be equal to the value pulled from the previous page which is where I am stuck.*

```
export class EditWeatherForecastComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Edit Data';
  baseUrl: string;
  ID: number;
  weatherForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private service: ApiService, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public http: HttpClient, private router: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.baseUrl = "https://localhost:44347/WeatherForecast";
    this.weatherForm = formBuilder.group({
      ID: this.forecast.ID,
      Date: new FormControl(),
      TemperatureC: new FormControl(),
      TemperatureF: new FormControl(),
      Summary: new FormControl(),

    });
  }

  forecasts: any = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshWeatherList();
    this.ID = +this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('ID');

    this.service.getWeatherListID(this.ID).subscribe((response: WeatherForecast) => {
    this.forecast = response;
    });
  }

  refreshWeatherList() {
    this.service.getForecast().subscribe(data => {
      this.forecasts = data;
    });
  }

  updateWeatherList() {
    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        'ID': this.weatherForm.value.ID.toString(),
        'date': this.weatherForm.value.Date.toString(),
        'temperatureC': this.weatherForm.value.TemperatureC.toString(),
        'temperatureF': this.weatherForm.value.TemperatureF.toString(),
        'summary': this.weatherForm.value.Summary.toString()
      }
    });

    console.log(params);
    this.http.put(this.baseUrl, {}, { params: params }).subscribe(data => {
      this.refreshWeatherList();
      console.log(data);

    });
  }

}
```

**EDIT HTML** *Included the HTML for the edit form to show how I currently take in data user-wise ideally we want to leave out an ID input box here because I want the ID to not be able to be decided by the user*

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <form [formGroup]="weatherForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="forecast.ID" name="ID" formControlName="ID"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="forecast.Date" name="Date" formControlName="Date"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">TemperatureC</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="forecast.TemperatureC" name="TemperatureC" formControlName="TemperatureC"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">TemperatureF</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="forecast.TemperatureF" name="TemperatureF" formControlName="TemperatureF"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Summary</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="forecast.Summary" name="Summary" formControlName="Summary"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" (click)="updateWeatherList()" >Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So your requirements are: Pass the ID value to the ID field and Disable ID field?

Comment: Essentially I want to pass the ID value to another component to be used as the input rather than having the user enter it themselves.